# VBA syntax for calling a subform's public function where the subform is a control variable?

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

I am trying to have the form call a subform's function on itself and am not sure what syntax I should use for that. My attempt is below.

In the Form:

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Form
    If ctl.ControlType = acSubform And InStr(ctl.Name, "Magnets") > 0 And ctl.Name <> "UnscheduledMagnets" Then
        'THE LINE BELOW DOESN'T WORK
        Call ctl.Form.Initialize2(CalendarArray(0, 1), CalendarArray(0, 0), strQuery, CInt(Mid(ctl!Name, 1, 1)))
    End If
Next ctl
```

In the Subform:

```
Public Sub Initialize2(intDay As Integer, intDate As Long, strQuery As String, intDivision As Integer)
    'Details not important since the function isn't even being called
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: This may work: forms("subformname").Initialize2 paremeters

Comment: Your syntax is correct and will work, so something else is going on. Try calling a simple MsgBox in the subfunction with only one parameter of type String for the messagebox prompt.

Comment: Are you getting some sort of an error with your attempt or just nothing happens?  Also do what Gustav said.

Comment: GUSTAV: the messagebox never comes up and I still get the ErrorHandler text from my Main() function. But when I comment out the lines that reference the subform function, I do not get the error.

Comment: ADRIAN: hmm that doesn't work either.

Comment: NEWD AND GUSTAV: So I commented out my ErrorHandler and found out that the parameter ctl!Name should have been ctl.Name instead!!!! So it works now. Thanks to all of you that commented on my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it wasn't working cause of my own stupidity... My syntax is all right, but one of my parameters references ctl!Name, a form control called Name which doesn't exist, instead of ctl.Name, which is the name of the subform. Wish I could vote a comment on my original post as the answer to my question, but I can't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Form_NameOfYourSubform.Initialize2(CalendarArray(0, 1), CalendarArray(0, 0), strQuery, CInt(Mid(ctl!Name, 1, 1)))
End If
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me since it doesn't call the function on the specific subform